# Column names of a CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I know it is possible to ***SELECT***, from *sys.columns* and from *tempdb.sys.columns* the names of the columns of a specific table.

Can the same be done from a **CTE**?

```
with SampleCTE as (
 Select 
   'Tom' as Name
  ,'Bombadill' as Surname
  ,99999 as Age
  ,'Withywindle' as Address
)
```

is there any way to know that the columns of this CTE are **Name,Surname,Age** and **Address**, without resorting to dumping the CTE result to a temporary table and reading the columns from there?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it. I also cannot imagine why you'd need to.

Comment: I need to unpivot the data from a variable select in a series of key->values (an hashtable in Powershell, a named array in other languages)
In order to UNPIVOT, you need to know in advance the column names on which to unpivot.

Comment: Nope, CTE aren't tables nor views, and their metadata isn't stored (the query overall is).

Comment: Sure, but i was thinking that a select from a CTE can be analyzed in order to know the column it outputs.. after all, they're extracted and displayed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a "dynamic" approach without actually using Dynamic SQL.

Unpivot (dynamic or not) would be more performant

**Example**

```
with SampleCTE as (
 Select 
   'Tom' as Name
  ,'Bombadill' as Surname
  ,99999 as Age
  ,'Withywindle' as Address
) 
Select C.*
 From SampleCTE A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','ExcludeOtherCol')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
Item    Value
Name    Tom
Surname Bombadill
Age     99999
Address Withywindle
```

Comment: I tested it and indeed it works with the CTE as the source of data.
As you say, it could be way slower (but that's not an issue in my scenario)
But with past experiences with XMLData in Sql.. will it break with data containing XML Tags? < > etc..?

Comment: @Aldo I just saw you added a sample CTE and updated my answer

Comment: i tried with some 'bad' data and it seems to be immune to < and > ... still any data is 'safe' with XML parsing?

Comment: ..while not properly an answer to the original question, this solves in an excellent way my problem. Many thanks John!

Comment: @Aldo Always happy to help

Comment: Upvoted for including Tom Bombadil in your sample data!  :)

Comment: Worked really well to track a function that may see more hierarchy levels in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

> **This dynamic management function takes a Transact-SQL statement as a parameter and describes the metadata of the first result set for the statement.**

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(
N'
with SampleCTE as (
 Select 
   ''Tom'' as Name
  ,''Bombadill'' as Surname
  ,99999 as Age
  ,''Withywindle'' as Address
)
SELECT * FROM SampleCTE
', NULL, NULL);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d5289faebf36a0d8c82247df9c82cd9f)**

Comment: I always have to hit myself when I see something like this... because, OF COURSE a utility like this is baked into the product by now!